# Status: 0/unconfirmed, in memory pool. Cnee's address expired and reject this transaction

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions

Internet connection was lost during transaction. Bitcoins gone, but no chance to confirm transaction at cnee side. So after some hours cnee's address expired and reject this trnsctn. Now, as 24H passed, status is still unconfirmed. 
As I expect, these funds will be returned for some time.
The question is - am I right and what is the time limit, usually, I have to start worrying after or what I can do now to return the bits. 
Thanks for advice.

Comment: Who or what is cnee?

Comment: Crypto exchange